# Printing Unicode characters in java

Tags: java, unicode

I'm developing a Sinhala-English Unicode translator on Java. When I print a Unicode character in a JTextPane, it only shows a blank box. But when I copy that box to the notepad in windows it shows me the letter.
The problem is that Java not showing the Unicode characters instead windows.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: LOL, Wikipedia suffers from the same problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_language

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specify a font that has the characters you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that the font you are using in your JTextPane does not fully support the Unicode range that you are trying to display. Try setting the text area's font to [something more Unicode-friendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_typefaces#0780-139F) (see the row labeled "Sinhala (80: 0D80–0DFF)").

Comment: @Thusitha Please accept the answer by clicking the check box next to the upvote number on the top left of the post. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how upvoting and accepting answers works on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hello Thusitha, can u explain your solution. Did you use FreeSerif font??